# Установка Windows 10 и Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, dual-boot

Я полностью запутался. Я установил Windows 10, затем Linux Ubuntu на один жёсткий диск. Проблема в том, что мне не предлагается при запуске компьютера выбрать ОС. Я следовал каким-то найденным инструкциям в интернете, но, судя по всему, сделал что-то неправильно или нарушил порядок действий, поэтому ничего не вышло.

Какую информацию я должен указать тут, чтобы мне смогли помочь?

Comment: `UEFI` включен или ты в `Legacy mode` ставил?

Comment: @don Rumata Ну я сейчас как раз с этим и разбираля - запустить диск в UEFI у меня так и не получилось - нет такого пункта в boot

Comment: А что прогружается тогда? Винда или линукс?

Comment: @don Rumata грузится Винда

Comment: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` с любого livecd решает проблему?

Comment: @don Rumata, в первый раз вижу этот совет, сейчас попробую) Я должен только исполнить эту команду или что-то ещё при этом? Нужно указывать раздел /dev/sda или оставить бух цифры?

Comment: @don Rumata без*

Comment: @don Rumata "Ошибка: не удалось получить канонический путь /cow"

Comment: 1. Скриншот из gparted твоих разделов. 2. Что за livecd пробовал?

Answer (score 5):

Если грузится Windows, то это означает, что СНАЧАЛА Вы установили Linux, а ПОТОМ - Widows. Инсталлятор винды не подозревает о том, что в природе существуют другие ОС, кроме Windows. Поэтому он тупо сносит IPL и grub становится недоступным. Есть два варианта:

1. Установить Windows, и только потом - Linux
2. Загрузиться с любого установочного (Linux) CD или флэшки и в главном меню выбрать нечто вроде "Восстановить загрузчик".

Answer (score 1):

Краткий мануал:

К примеру, установка с нуля:
Устанавливаем Windows, разбиваем жёсткий диск при установке, к примеру локальный диск C (70 Гб), на диск D (150 Гб). Резервируешь для Linux пустое место в размере от 20 до 30 Гб, не форматируешь, оставляешь диск не размеченным.
**(Размеры я написал К ПРИМЕРУ!)**

После установки Windows грузишься с диска (флешки) Ubuntu. При установке, выбери пункт "Разметка вручную". Перед тобой откроется таблица разметки. Тот раздел, который ты оставил не размеченным - выбери его, в качестве точки монтирования установи "/" - это корневой раздел, файловая система ext4. Если будет ругаться на файл подкачки - игнорируй, т.к. Ubuntu скоро прекратит поддержку swap, да и в принципе он тебе не нужен будет. На этом всё. Если спросит про установки загрузчика Grub, просто ответь положительно и всё. Он перепишет bootloader с поддержкой Windows + Linux.

При таком раскладе у тебя домашний каталог "home" твоего пользователя Linux тоже запишется в этот раздел. Поэтому, если хочешь хранить файлы пользователя отдельно, резервируй для него место. На другом языке - "home" это типа как диск D в Windows, но + там ещё хранятся настройки пользователя. Так что он ещё и "системный") Поэтому при установке можешь выбрать для системы "/" раздел, а для пользователя создать область на жёстком диске для хранения файлов, выдели сколько тебе угодно и укажи точку монтирования "home".

Для более детальной установки уже можешь использовать продвинутые настрйоки. Выше - это я тебе описал как для новичка. Но всё же стоит прочесть мануалы по установке. Лучше, конечно, boot вынести в отдельный раздел. Но это уже как вникнешь в суть.